# CSS `background-image` not working with `all: unset`?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, background-image

I'm working on a stylized `<hr />` in a library that I'm writing.

This library has a root element/component that uses `all: initial` to populate things like `font-size` which is used to change the relative size of the component. However, I'm running into a problem where I want to use `all: unset` on all other components.

This seems to break (in production but not storybook?) the `background-image` that I have set on my `<hr />`.

Here is a self contained example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <div style={{ all: 'initial' }}>
      <h1>
        Why is <code>background-image</code> not shoing here?
      </h1>
      <hr
        style={{
          ...(toggle ? { all: 'unset' } : {}),
          border: 'none',
          backgroundRepeat: `no-repeat`,
          backgroundSize: `100% 0.05em`,
          backgroundPosition: `center`,
          backgroundImage: `linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, hsl(0, 200%, 90%) 10%, hsl(0, 200%, 90%) 48%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 48%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 52%, hsl(0, 200%, 90%) 52%, hsl(0, 200%, 90%) 90%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)`,
          color: `hsl(0, 0%, 20%)`,
          textAlign: `center`,
          height: `0.75em`,
        }}
      />

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setToggle((t) => !t);
        }}
      >
        {!toggle ? "Add 'all: unset'" : "Remove 'all unset'"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-koin4c?file=App.tsx) of the problem as well.

What am I missing here? It has to be an `unset` property, right?
But I haven't been able to find the one that's causing this behavior.

This happens regardless of React/JSX/webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Has 2 problems:

##### About `all` of CSS:

it sets all the properties of course including the base ones so you have to manually set them after `unset`:

```
<hr
        style={{
          ...(toggle ? { all: 'unset' } : {}),

+         width: '100%',
+         display: 'block',
+         position: 'relative',

          border: 'none',
          backgroundRepeat: `no-repeat`,
          backgroundSize: `100% 0.05em`,
          backgroundPosition: `center`,
          backgroundImage: `linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, hsl(0, 200%, 90%) 10%, hsl(0, 200%, 90%) 48%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 48%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 52%, hsl(0, 200%, 90%) 52%, hsl(0, 200%, 90%) 90%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)`,
          color: `hsl(0, 0%, 20%)`,
          textAlign: `center`,
          height: `0.75em`,
        }}
      />
```

##### About `all` of React:

about `all` instead of putting `all: <value>` in html react lists all unset attributes which causes other attributes to be removed the solution is to use `class` instead of object for `style`

> if you only render once without turning `all` on and off then you don't need to worry about this problem

Comment: Oh, um so I didn't even notice that react is unsetting things in the StackBlitz bc mine is using `className`. That's crazy weird. I'm going to play around with this a bit tomorrow! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

From chrome F12:
The display: inline property prevents height from having an effect.
Try setting display to something other than inline.